# How to APA cite in LATEX

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I want to cite like this: According to **Alvarado et al (2009)** the following algorithm is more efficient than...

I can only cite like this: According to **(Alvarado et al, 2009)**... using \parencite{06} and as you can see the output is not what I needed.

I'm new with latex and your help would be welcome

Comment: Welcome. If you don't want parentheses, don't use *paren*cite. There are other cite commands. Try out `\autocite`, `\textcite` or just `\cite` to get your wanted output. Furthermore, it would help if you provide a Minimal Working Example with the needed packages and options you use (which can alter the outcome), so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: I've take the liberty of deleting the `apacite` tag since you appear to be interested in a biblatex/biber-based solution. Feel free to revert.

Comment: Textcite is almost perfect the problem is when I have two authors, it appears Joan Deer & Michael Jackson instead of Deer J. & Jackson M.

Comment: `\textcite` is definitely the command you want to be using with `biblatex` for the general output you'd like to see. If the exact form of the output is not to your liking, you need to ask a new question detailing what you see at the moment, what you would like to see and how you generate your citations at the moment. In other words: We need to see a compilable example document that reproduces your citation setup and generates a problematic citation of the form you describe.

Comment: @lukeflo Do you want to type up a quick answer here so that the question can be marked as resolved. The answer that's currently posted below does not really address the main issue as it is about `apacite`, while the question is most likely about `biblatex` (`\parencite` is only defined by `biblatex`).

Comment: @moewe I can have a look but not before evening. So if you've time earlier, go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your wanted output in APA style using `biblatex` you should load that style as package-option.

If you then use `\textcite`, it creates exactly the output you want:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{testbib.bib}
@article{bouche2006,
  author    = {Bouche, Thierry},
  journal   = {Tugboat},
  title     = {A {pdfLaTeX}-based automated journal production system},
  year      = {2006},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {45--50},
  volume    = {27},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{testbib.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{title}
\label{sec:intro}

What \textcite{bouche2006} states is very interesting.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: apa style intext citation]

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for apacite, the `natbibapa` option to apacite will also load `natbib` with APA's preferred options. You can then use `\citet` rather than `\citep` or `\cite` to get the citation the way you are wanting it.

Comment: I think your answer works -- very well, in fact -- with BibTeX, the `apacite` package, and the `apacite` bibliography style. However, the OP would appear to be more interested in a biber/biblatex-type solution.